# Coordinates of a vertex of a triangle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles

Here is the problem:
There is a triangle with vertices $A,B,C$ in a cartesian coordinate system, where coordinates of points $A$ and $B$ and the angle $\alpha=\measuredangle ABC$ are given. The ratio $\frac{\overline{BC}}{\overline{AC}}$ is equal to $k$. Express coordinates of the point $C$ in terms of coordinates of points $A,B$ and $\alpha,k$.
Edit: I got an immense quadratic equation and hoped to maybe hear some suggestions about your workflow for this kind of problem.

Comment: Have you drawn an image to get your bearings?

Comment: I did, I have been working on this problem for about 3 hours now, but the only thing I get is a huge quadratic equation, so I hoped there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially assume coordinates $A(1,0)$ and $B(0,0)$. (You can get any others using translations, rotations around $(0,0)$, and stretch/shrink, which all keep angles and distance ratios the same.)

Now the $\alpha$'s vertex is $(0,0)$ and the quadratic equation turns out much simpler.

**EDIT:** The transformations after you've calculated the simplified C:

First rotate and stretch/shrink around $(0,0)$ so that $(1,0)$ becomes $(X,Y)=(x_a-x_b,y_a-y_b)$. This is how it's done:
$$(x,y) \mapsto (Xx-Yy, Yx+Xy)$$
Then translations:
$$(x,y) \mapsto (x+x_b, y+y_b)$$
Easy-peasy!

Comment: Oh, that Edit explanation is really helpful. I'll see if I can go through with it.

Comment: By the way, there will be two possible solutions of point $C$. One on one side of the line $AB$ and one symmetrical about this line. What is the quickest way to calculate the coordinates of the second solution?

Comment: @bartekac Before transformation, one is $(x_c,y_c)$ and the other one is $(x_c,-y_c)$. But would that make the angle $-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$?

Comment: Right I see it now.
In the question I meant the measure of $\alpha$ not the $\alpha$ itself, so technically I need to consider both solutions.